# Pc-Stable from pcalg

Tags: machine-learning

I am using the pc-stable from the package ‘pcalg’ version 2.0-10 to learn the structure . what I understand this algorithm does not effect the the order of the input data because it is order_independent. when I run it with different order ,I got different graph. can any one help me with this issue and this is my code.

```
library(pracma)

randindexMatriax <- matrix(0,10,ncol(TrainData))
numberUnique_val_col = vector()
pdf("Graph for Test PC Stable with random order.pdf")
```

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
   for (i in 1:10)
  {

```
randindex<-randperm(1:ncol(TrainData))
randindexMatriax[i,]<-randindex
TrainDataRandOrder<-data[,randindex]

V <- colnames( TrainDataRandOrder)
UD <-data.frame(TrainDataRandOrder)
```

numberUnique_val_col=  sapply(UD,function(x)length(unique(x)))

suffStat <- list(dm =  TrainDataRandOrder,nlev =           c(numberUnique_val_col[1],numberUnique_val_col[2],                                                         numberUnique_val_col[3],numberUnique_val_col[4],
                                                numberUnique_val_col[5],numberUnique_val_col[6],                                                  numberUnique_val_col[7],
                                                   numberUnique_val_col[8],numberUnique_val_col[9],
                                                     numberUnique_val_col[10],numberUnique_val_col[11],
                                                     numberUnique_val_col[12],numberUnique_val_col[13],
                                                     numberUnique_val_col[14],numberUnique_val_col[15],
                                                     numberUnique_val_col[16],numberUnique_val_col[17],
                                                     numberUnique_val_col[18],numberUnique_val_col[19],                                                     numberUnique_val_col[20]), adaptDF = FALSE)

pc.fit <- pc(suffStat, indepTest= disCItest, alpha=0.01, labels=V, fixedGaps = NULL, fixedEdges = NULL,NAdelete = TRUE, m.max = Inf,skel.method = "stable", conservative = TRUE,solve.confl = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

The "Stable" part of PC-Stable only affects the Skeleton phase of the algorithm. The Orientation phase is still order-dependent. Do the two graphs have identical "skeletons"? That is, if you convert all directed edges into undirected edges, are the two graphs identical?

If not, you may have uncovered a bug in `pcalg`! Please post a sample dataset and two orderings of the columns that produce graphs with different skeletons.